# Replacing characters using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to remove commas from all of my textboxes on keyup.  I came up with the script below but it's not working.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
<script>
    $("input[type='text']").keyup
    (
        function () 
        {
            alert('1');
            $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[,]/g, ""));
        }
    );
</script>
```

**NOTE:** please excuse the $ in Script.  SO won't let me post it otherwise...

Comment: No, alert isn't fireing.

Comment: It looks like someone was able to save it with the correct script tag. Please read the NOTE i have added regarding the $ in script

Comment: It works fine, you're just missing `$(document).ready`. But why are you using a regex? This is a simple string replacement.

Comment: @Josh, String replace only gets the first instance right?  I figured this way would allow people to copy in values with multiple commas and remove them all.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah, you're right. I forgot about the case in which a user might type two or more commas before lifting the key.

Comment: @Abe Miessler: with a reputation of more than 3k you still don't know how to format code in your question? Mark the code in the textfield and press the code button (the one with zeroes and ones in it) or indent the code block with 4 spaces.

Comment: @jigfox... Yes, with a reputation of more than 3k I DO know how to format code in my question.  That's why the code in my question is formatted....  When, I included the script tag it would throw a "connection reset" error.  Feel free to add to the meta.SO post i created this morning if you have something of value to contribute...  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63728/anyone-else-getting-random-the-connection-was-reset-errors-when-posting-a-quest

Comment: @Abe Miessler: Sorry, I didn't mean to offense you! I was just wondering. And so I wrote how to format code, because here are a lot of users who don't know.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might want to wrap that whole chunk of code in a document ready function

```
$(function() {
  $("input:text").keyup(function() {
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[,]/g, ""));
  });
});
```

You can read all about this on the [jQuery documentation site](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Answer (score 6):

As others have mentioned, make sure you're using $(document).ready() - http://api.jquery.com/ready/.  Also, instead of replacing commas on keyup, you should disallow them on keypress by returning false:

```
$(document.ready(function () { 
    $("input[type=text]").keypress(function (evt) {
        if (String.fromCharCode(evt.which) == ",")
            return false;
    });
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/QshDd/

This gives a more professional feel, the "," is blocked without appearing and then disappearing when you release the key.  Like your solution, however, this won't catch copying and pasting commas into your input.  For that, you can hook into the *onpaste* or *onchange* event.

If you want to stick with keyup and replace, you don't really need to mess around with jQuery wrappings, you can access the *value* property directly:

```
$(document.ready(function () { 
    $("input[type=text]").keyup(function (evt) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/,/g, "");
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 for being the only answer to actually give OP a better way of doing what he's trying to do and not just say "wrap in `$(document).ready()`."

Comment: @Josh: thanks :-) Alas, I fear the OP might have skipped my advice.

Comment: And what about `<input type="number">`? Try tu put [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QshDd/15/) characters like 555s. It doesn't replace only non-numeric character, but whole input. Where is problem?

Comment: @Ajax: when an `<input type="number">` has a value that is not a number, its `value` property is an empty string.  Therefore, you can't do string replacement for non-numeric characters.  I would take a look at the first part of my answer and disallow the erroneous input altogether.

Comment: @Andy E: What a pity... Deleting character looks better, but thanks for the answer, I'll use it.

Answer (score 3):

It's working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/vsnrc/1/

Comment: Unfortunately not working with jQuery 3.x ... only with 1.4.x and 2.x ... Any idea how to make this work with jQuery 3.x ?

Comment: @Levchik First line needs to change to `$(window).on('load',function(){ ` according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37738732/jquery-3-0-url-indexof-error

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("input[type='text']").live('keyup',function () 
        {
            alert('1');
            $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[,]/g, ""));
        });
    });
</script>
```

If your input is in an update panel, or added after the binding takes place, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
        $("input[type='text']").keyup
        (
            function () 
            {
                alert('1');
                $(this).val($(this).val().replace(',', ""));
            }
        );
    </script>
```