# How to input characters at the caret in a contenteditable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

How do I input a character, with either JQuery or plain JavaScript, as if it had been typed?

I have a `contenteditable` section, and am intercepting user input in order to replace certain characters (for example straight quotes with curly ones). I have the following JQuery to intercept a character, but am not sure of the best way to input the new character.

```
$('.editor').keypress(function(e) {
    console.log(e.which);
    if (e.which === 39) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // replace with curly quotes
    }
});
```

Comment: are you looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661415/replacing-characters-using-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about document.execCommand:

```
$('.editor').keypress(function(e) {
  console.log(e.which);
  if (e.which === 39) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, 'String To Insert');
  }
});
```

insertHTML doesn't work in IE so use:

```
document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML('html to insert');
```

A list of commands and examples can be found at:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla

---

P.S. I think e.which will report 0 in certain browsers so do something like:

```
var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
```

Comment: Using insertText where HTML isn't needed, but this is what I was after, thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work in IE: the `InsertHTML` command is not supported.

Comment: jQuery normalizes `e.which` to report the character code in most situations in all supported browsers, so the last part is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
$('.editor').keypress(function(e) {
    console.log(e.which);
    if (e.which === 39) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).text(function(index, text){
            return text.replace(/"/gi, '-'); // <--Change this to replace the " with what you need.
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I think I confused matters by talking about replacements, I basically just need to know how to input a character at the caret programatically. There is no character to replace in the element, as I have intercepted it.

Comment: Ahh I see. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064089/inserting-a-text-where-cursor-is-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: Having problems with most of those approaches which are, I think, down to dealing with contenteditable, not a traditional text input of some variety.

Comment: Ahh, well, this question deals with that specifically: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690752/insert-html-at-cursor-in-a-contenteditable-div